# selenium very similar xpaths?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have two buttons on a page that have really similar xpaths -

the button im trying to click -

```
/html/body/div[@id='wrapper']/div[@id='content']/div[@id='contentarea']/div[@id='votecontent']/div[@id='votetext']/div[@id='voteboxes']/div[@id='votenow'][2]/form/input[2]
```

and the other button im trying to ignore -

```
/html/body/div[@id='wrapper']/div[@id='content']/div[@id='contentarea']/div[@id='votecontent']/div[@id='votetext']/div[@id='voteboxes']/div[@id='votenow'][1]/form/input[2]
```

the only difference between the two is the

```
[@id='votenow'][1]
```

and

```
[@id='votenow'][2]
```

but I can't figure out how to interact with the one that has the votenow[2], whichever way I go about it, it always seems to interact with the first one because that's the first one it finds

this is for java using the firefox driver, any suggestions would be great :)

Comment: can you post the html code from id="voteboxes" on?

Answer (score 3):

Just find them both and get the desired one by index:

```
List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("your xpath"));
WebElement secondButton = buttons.get(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

## First

Please talk to your developers! It is **really bad practice** to assign the same id to two different elements (in your case buttons) on the same page! It makes life for DEV and QA unnecessarily harder than it need be!

## Second

The xpath-expressions you posted already contain the differentiation between these two buttons. So you just need to find the first one and click it.

## via xpath:

You can use xpath - should be enough to search for the elements with `id="votenow"`. As said before, you can be pretty precise in this case and already filter for the 2nd button:

```
WebElement button02 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='votenow'][2]/form/input[2]"));
button02.click();
```

## via id:

As @alecxe already pointed out, you can also first go for a more general search of several elements and then filter the right one out. Personally I would use the id in this case:

```
List<WebElement> buttonWrappers = driver.findElements(By.id("votenow"));

// you want the button-input-element in the 2nd wrapper element, indexing starts at 0, so do this:
WebElement button02 = buttonWrappers.get(1).findElement(By.xpath("//input[2]"));
// since it seems there are several input elements below the desired div, you can use xpath again
```

Comment: It's not just really bad practice, [the HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id) defines that ids must be unique on the page... but I see it all too often.